# Java: event objects filtered by startDate just work for one-day events

Tags: java, date, events, filter

i am looking for a function that helps me with the following problem:
There is a Java class called "Event". The "Event" class has the attributes "startDate" and "endDate". Some events are not just one day long they exist for example 2 weeks.

Than there is a dropdown menu where you can choose a date of the next following days. The events which have the same "startDate" of the one which is choosen will appear.

The Problem:
Events they exsist longer than just one day will only appear when you choose the "startDate". It should also appear when the event still take place on the choosen date.

For Example:
startDate is 2016-06-20
endDate is 2016-06-25

In the Dropdown you choose the date 2016-06-22, than the event will not appear.

Thank you a lot for any help.

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you showed some code with input + expected output.

Comment: Did you write the code that populates the dropdown menu?  If so, please show the code.

Comment: This Question makes no sense. It has sentences that contradict one another. Please read the Question out loud to yourself and rewrite until it makes sense. And add examples of data that match a query and data that misses a query.